Unable to connect to wi-fi
I recently bought a laptop on which I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I am no computer expert. I downloaded the program on a USB stick and installed it besides Windows 11 on my computer. That was easy.
My problem however is that I am unable to connect to the Wi-Fi. I have no problem connecting if I use Windows. I tried to find out where I could activate the Wi-Fi on Ubuntu. I saw that when clicking at the top right corner, the possibility to activate the Wi-Fi should appear on the pop-up screen but it does not. I have Bluetooth, keyboard, etc but no Wi-Fi.
I tried to start the process all over, downloading on a USB stick and so on but the problem persists.
Any suggestion on simple ways to resolve this?

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos
